# awk - combine lines variables & print as columns

Tags: awk

I do have a problem that is too difficult for me, but believe it can be solved very easily in awk.
My data looks like this:

> 8377885 8384365 8385357 8385877  @ 8378246 8384786 8385450 8386102
>   66999065 66999928 67091529 @ 66999090 67000051 67091593

It's different lines that that have '@' exactly in the middle of them. I want to:
1.Combine line elements separated with '@' from first to last;
2.Print all combined elements as column.
Preferred output would look like this:

> 8377885  8378246
>   8384365  8384786
>   8385357  8385450
>   8385877  8386102
>   8390268  8390996
>   66999065 66999090
>   66999928 67000051
>   67091529 67091593

Hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below will work:

```
awk -F"@" '{n=split($1,a," ");split($2,b," ");for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[i],b[i]}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> awk -F"@" '{n=split($1,a," ");split($2,b," ");for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[i],b[i]}' temp
8377885 8378246
8384365 8384786
8385357 8385450
8385877 8386102
66999065 66999090
66999928 67000051
67091529 67091593
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you have a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[@ ]+" } { for (i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) { printf "%s %s\n", $i, $(NF/2+i) } }' infile
```

That yields:

```
8377885 8378246
8384365 8384786
8385357 8385450
8385877 8386102
66999065 66999090
66999928 67000051
67091529 67091593
```